# Rails asset pipeline with ES6 modules and browserify

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, commonjs, browserify, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to implement something with the rails asset pipeline that is proving harder than I'd hoped.

In order to structure the app cleanly, I plan to use a module system for the javascript. For this I want to use CommonJS modules, but I'd like to write them using the new ES6 syntax for future compatibility.

I've found the ES6 module transpiler extension for the asset pipeline, which works well, but this only converts it into the CommonJS format. I still need to get this into JS that the browser understands. For that I'm looking at using Browserify but my problem lies in combining these 2.

The module transpiler works in a per file basis, but browserify works by checking all of the files needed. The problem is that browserify can't use the original files as they're no in CommonJS format, they're in ES6, so it needs the transpiled versions, but because that happens in the pipeline, I can't point browserify at a file.

Are there any ways around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) gem. For ES6, you would use a `transform` such as this one: https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify

Update some months later: I still recommend the same path but if you can get off of the asset pipeline, I highly recommend going to webpack or browserify directly. The asset pipeline has some benefits but in my experience, trying to make JavaScript a first-class citizen is painful with it and the benefits outweigh the drawbacks (for me).

Comment: Hey. I've already got the browserify running through the asset pipeline and it works very well. My only issue is that I can't seem to have it wait until the other sprockets processors have processed the file (such as erb or in my case, ES6) and then have browserify process that output.

Comment: @PaReeOhNos Do you have some code? Maybe example git repo? I'm not having that problem but my use case is pretty simple -- just .js files. I would ask why are you putting JavaScript in erb? Not sure on ES6 (would like to see example). I've been working on browserify-rails  -- it and browserify definitely still have some pain points.

Comment: I'm not so much using ERB specifically, more just as an example. But the ES6 extension works in the same way. i.e you give the files an es6.js extension. My issue lies in that browserify rails works over all of the javascript files, however all of my files were in ES6 format, so I needed to run browserify on the source AFTER it had been processed by the ES6 processor. I've since dropped the ES6 as I couldn't find a clean solution as I was hoping to keep it entirely in the asset pipeline

Comment: @PaReeOhNos Browserify supports transforms so the browserify way to do this would be to use something like this: https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify -- I've added support for configuration to browserify that would let you add `--transform` as needed. It isn't into master yet.

Comment: Will definitely look at that. I couldn't find that when I started work on it, only ones like coffeeify, so glad to see that's available now :)

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try [Seth Vincent's](http://learnjs.io/blog/2014/03/17/using-browserify-with-rails/) approach, where he uses package.json, and npm scripts to run all JavaScript tasks, and only uses bundle.js in the asset pipeline. You could then shell out to npm tasks from your Rakefile. I like his approach because it opens up the modern JS tool chain for JS tasks.

Comment: Looks like a nice approach. I'll take a look :)

Comment: The ugly parts with this are you need 3 files (1 for sprockets, 1 for CommonJS and 1 for the output of browserify aka the 'bundle') and then you also need to check the generated bundle into source code or cover all the ways of starting Rails to be sure that the bundle gets generated... Even if you fix that, you still have two files. Not horrible and I do like being isolated from RoR but something to think about.

Comment: Three files and NPM will always win out over order-based operations and clunky sprockets.